# How to attach checked event to CheckBox in DataTemplate in wpf

Tags: wpf, events, datatemplate

Hi I am having a `CheckBox` defined in a `DataTemplate` which is defined in resource.Xaml file.  I am using this `DataTemplate` in my user control. I am adding this `DataTemplate` dynamically to a `GridView`. Now I want to fire the checked event of a `CheckBox`.  How will I attach the event?  My Xaml is like this:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView></GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that the CheckBox.Checked event bubbles up to its parent controls:

```
<ListView CheckBox.Checked="YourCheckedEventHandler">
    ...
</ListView>
```

Obviously you'll have to check the item whose CheckBox was checked in the event handler. The easiest way to do that is to look at the DataContext of the sender parameter, or possibly the Source property on the "e" parameter.

Comment: This check box is in DataTemplate which I have to attach it to one of the GridViewColumn dynamically. Also DataTemplate I am using is not in same file It is defined in Resource.Xaml file. so I am unable to use above statement.

Comment: It doesn't matter where the DataTemplate lives. If you have CheckBox.Checked="..." on a parent control your event handler will get called when the CheckBox is checked. Put it on the Window itself if you have to.